# How to programatically configure binding to force JSON encoding of WCF messages?

Tags: wcf, json, binding

I'm creating a custom binding (mostly for diagnostic purposes initially) that programatically changes thw way WCF messages are encoded. Here's what it looks like:

```
public class ConfigurableNetTcpBinding : Binding
{
    public enum MessageEncoding
    {
        Text,
        Binary,
        MTOM,
        ByteStream,
        JSON,
    };

    private TcpTransportBindingElement transport;
    private MessageEncodingBindingElement encoding;
    public ConfigurableNetTcpBinding(MessageEncoding encoding = MessageEncoding.Binary, bool enableMessageCounters = false)
        : base()
    {
        EnableMessageCounters = enableMessageCounters;
        Encoding = encoding;
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();
        elements.Add(this.encoding);
        elements.Add(this.transport);
        return elements;
    }
    public override string Scheme
    {
        get { return this.transport.Scheme; }
    }

    public long MaxReceivedMessageSize
    {
        get { return transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize; }
        set { transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = value; }
    }

    public TransferMode TransferMode
    {
        get { return transport.TransferMode; }
        set { transport.TransferMode = value; }
    }

    public MessageEncoding Encoding { get; private set; }

    public bool EnableMessageCounters { get; private set; }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        MessageEncodingBindingElement messageEncoder;
        switch (Encoding)
        {
            default:
            case MessageEncoding.Text:
                messageEncoder = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                break;

            case MessageEncoding.Binary:
                messageEncoder = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                break;

            case MessageEncoding.MTOM:
                messageEncoder = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                break;

            case MessageEncoding.ByteStream:
                messageEncoder = new ByteStreamMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                break;

            case MessageEncoding.JSON:
                WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webEncoder = new WebMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                // Um... what goes here to to configure the webEncoder to serialize with JSON vs POX
                messageEncoder = webEncoder;
                break;
        }

        transport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
        encoding = EnableMessageCounters ? new CountingEncoderBindingElement(messageEncoder) : messageEncoder;
    }
}
```

Ignore the `CountingEncoderBindingElement`... it's just a wrapper for counting bytes on the wire. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to configure WebMessageEncodingBindingElement so that it always serialized messages as JSON. What am I missing? All the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.webmessageencodingbindingelement.aspx) say this is the encoding element to use for JSON encoding and the docs say to use the `Encoding` constructor to set that mode, but `Encoding` does not have any options for JSON... it's all about Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Web message format is controlled by WebHttpBehavior. I am interested if you will be able to make it work over net tcp.

Comment: Interesting. There shouldn't be anything http-specific about the message encoding format... at least I hope not :) I'll keep digging and will surely post the solution if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no property you can set on WebMessageEncodingBindingElement to always serialize message to JSON. The reason is that the the encoding element actually looks for a certain header in outgoing messages, and if the header is present, it writes out those messages to JSON.

To see what I mean, check out the implementations of WebMessageEncondingBindingElement.WriteMessage(...) via Reflector or a similar tool.

So, you have two options here:

(1) Insert the header on all of your outgoing messages, perhaps using a message interceptor

(2) Extract out JsonMessageEncodingBindingElement (which is private), rename/reuse it, and use it as your own custom binding element. Voila!

Hope that helps.